# Javascript, context (this) of the calling function

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code

```
var o = {
    f: function() {
        console.log(this);
    }
}

var o2 = {
    h:function(m){m()}
};

o2.h(o.f)
```

console prints --> window

can anyone explain why I've got windows instead of o2 ?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with closures at all.

Comment: @Denis the question is not how to fix it, rather why is it happening in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value of `this` is determined by the specifics of the actual call to a function, and *nothing else*.  The fact that your function "f" was declared as a property of the "o" object, or that it happens to be called by a function that's got "o2" as its `this` value, has absolutely nothing to do with it. Because the function is ultimately called without any "receiver" object, the value of `this` is by default the global object (`window`).

If you want "f" to be called with "o" as the reference, or "o2", you can use the `.bind()` method that the function inherits from the Function prototype:

```
o2.h(o.f.bind(o2));
```